# How to secure a stacked ikea kura bed

Tags: furniture, wooden-furniture, bedroom

So I have 2 kura beds

I want to stack them on top of each other. Something similar to image below. My question is how do I secure it. It will just be 1 bed, so the top kura bed will not have to support any weight other than the toddler leaning on it (hanging on it when I'm not looking?).

My initial thoughts are:

- Gorilla glue all along the edge
- Some kind of brace between them in addition (what kind of would I need?)
- Secure it to the wall along the studs

Would the above be secure enough for toddler use?

[image: kura bed]

Answer (score 1):

IKEA furniture is pretty well engineered, and by that I mean, they make it *just about* strong enough to be used as intended by the manufacturer.  There isn't a lot of overstrength to accommodate weird uses.  If the manufacturer **intended** that to be done, Both these would be true:

1. An explanation on how to do it would be included in the instructions for the bed.  And
2. A testing lab such as UL, TUV, CSA, etc. will have tested the design, and certified it to be safe.

If either of those things is not true, then either a) **do not do it**, or b) build a cantilevered or ceiling-hung platform to carry the weight of the upper bed *even if the lower one is removed*.

Comment: [The instructions for the bed I found on their shop](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/kura-reversible-bed__AA-843436-6_pub.pdf) don't include any info on how to stack them or secure them to the wall.

Comment: Thanks - need to figure out how i can add ceiling supports.

Comment: IMO, a lot can go wrong with suspending the bed from the ceiling if not done properly, I would only trust it bolted through the joists under sheer force and that would involve cutting up some drywall. I'd probably go with a freestanding outer cage that would support the upper bed, but then at that point I'd skip the $400 beds and build the entire thing myself.

Answer (score -2):

["Furniture Tip-Over Deaths Are On the Rise for Children".](https://people.com/home/report-finds-furniture-tip-overs-cause-injuries-every-17-minutes/) Why design something that a child would be tempted to climb and that might collapse under her or him? Unless *both* beds were attached firmly to studs, and the beds were attached firmly to each other, I wouldn't even think of creating an ersatz bunk bed. Even then, you don't know if the legs of the lower bed could stand the weight of an occupied bed above plus its own occupant.

Why would you think that a child would never climb to the top bunk??

Also, even well-designed bunk beds have been [cited as dangers](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/06/080602075809.htm).

Comment: Please read the question before saying 'unless you do the things you said you will do...'  Not sure the point of this response since its obvious that I want to make sure it's well secured.

Comment: Read the answer: securing the bed to the wall is **not** sufficient to ensure that stacking one on top of another is safe. Nor is a ceiling designed to bear the weight of a bed with children.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The report you cite seems a little pointless. Surely falling from a hight poses a danger, as crossing a road, taking an airplane or life in general. In this report the actual rate is not even stated. How many sleep in bunkbeds and don't get hurt? - just as a comparsion...